# Perl: A function that takes hash as input and iterates through both values and keys

Tags: perl

In Perl, how do you make a function that takes hash as input and iterates through both values and keys?

For example, say I have this cute input

```
      my %role2numbers = ( Role->{Dog} => 6,
                           Role->{Cat} => 3,
                           Role->{Mouse} => 1, );
```

Where Role->{Dog} are unique constants. Think of them as 1, 2 and 3.

And this method:

```
sub make_zoo{
     my %number_members_for_role = @_;          
     my $database_operation = SomeDBIModule::Table->new();
     my $rows = $database_operation->select();

     while (my ($role, $num) = each %number_members_for_role) {
        for my $i ( @$rows + 1 .. @$rows + $num ) {
            $database_operation->insert(
                +{  zoo_id         => 1,
                    name            => "name".$i,
                    type            => $role,
                 }             
            );                
        }                     
    }                         

 }
```

But when I do

```
       make_zoo ( %role2numbers);
```

it does not generate what I want.

It adds 6 Dogs, 3 Cats and 1 Mouse. But the dogs are called name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6 and when the loop goes to cat, the cats are called name1, name2 and name3 again when they should be called, name7, name8 and name9.

Any ideas?

Comment: This *should* work fine. Why don't you print the values of `$num`, `$i` and `$role` inside the loop to see if your assumptions are correct?

Comment: @amon sorry it worked fine. the problem was actually that the names are repeated. name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6 and then when it goes to cat, name1 again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are restarting the count at `@$rows+1` on each iteration of the while loop.  Try:

```
 my $i = @$rows;
 while (my ($role, $num) = each %number_members_for_role) {
    for my $role_num ( 1 .. $num ) {
        $database_operation->insert(
            +{  zoo_id         => 1,
                name            => "name".++$i,
                type            => $role,
             }             
        );                
    }                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time your for loop ends , the $i is reset to the same number $rows.So ,you have to save the $i every time the for loop ends.